# Matlab: finding polar coordinates from cartesian coordinates

Tags: matlab, function, multiple-variable-return

I am a newcomer to Matlab and programming in general. My Cartesian to polar conversion function that I wrote doesn't work.

```
syms x y
function [r,theta]=something[x,y] 
  r=(x^2+y^2)^.5
  theta=atan(x/y)
end
```

Comment: @RyanK, please don't use inline code syntax for things that are not code, like product names.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is create a function script file, but you have a non-function declaration statement at the beginning of your file.  You can't do this.  As such, you need to remove the `syms x y` statement at the beginning of your code.  Also, you aren't declaring your function properly.  You need to use **round** braces, not square braces to define your input parameters.

I would also use `atan2` instead of `atan` because it finds the proper four-quadrant arc-tangent of the Cartesian coordinates.  Also, use `sqrt` not `^.5` to take the square root.  It's more stable.  Also, to properly handle vector inputs, you need to make sure that `x` and `y` use `.^2` in the `r` calculation and not `^2`. Therefore, do this instead:

```
function [r,theta]=something(x,y) %// Change
r=sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2); %// Change
theta=atan2(y, x); %// Change
end
```

Place that into a file called `something.m`, then you can go into the command prompt and do this:

```
[r,theta] = something(x,y);
```

`x` and `y` are the `x` and `y` values of your Cartesian coordinates.  What's great is that `x` and `y` can be a single value, a vector or a matrix of any size.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `cart2pol` function:

```
[theta, rho] = cart2pol(x, y)
```

Or do this:

```
  theta = atan2(y, x)     % use atan2() instead of atan()
  rho = sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2) % use sqrt() instead of .^5
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy with **complex numbers**. Specifically, if the given Cartesian coordinates are interpreted as the real and imaginary parts of a complex number, then the polar coordinates are the **magnitude** ([`abs`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/abs.html)) and **argument** ([`angle`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/angle.html)) of that complex number:

```
>> z = x+1j*y;
>> r = abs(z);
>> theta = angle(z);
```